# Python Inserting data into Sql Server

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

Struggling to figure out why this isnt working. I don't get any errors but it will not write to the table.

```
import pyodbc
connprod = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=master;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursorprod = connprod.cursor()

conndev = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=master;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursordev = conndev.cursor()

connlocal=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=DBA;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursorlocal = connlocal.cursor()

cursorprod.execute("SELECT Servername = @@servername    ,Date = getdate()   ,wait_type  ,waiting_tasks_count    ,wait_time_ms   ,max_wait_time_ms   ,signal_wait_time_ms FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats GO")
rows = cursorprod.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    cursorlocal.execute('insert into dba.dbo.dm_os_wait_stats values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', row)
    cursorlocal.commit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your example is accurate, you're not calling the [commit method](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#commit):

```
cursorlocal.commit()
```

Comment: `commit` is not the same as `commit()`. You are not calling the method. If you remove the indent the commit will be called after all `execute()` calls. It just depends on what you want to do.